# How to use google account in your own android app?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

i have an android app which uses data stored in an google appengines datastore.
Every user has his own data. Im searching for a good way to use a google account for authentication and as a primary key in the database.

Can i use the AuthToken generated by the AccountManager? What is the best way to do this?

Thx a lot,
Ray

Answer (score 1):

You can follow Nick Johnson's approach: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app.

And yes you can use AuthToken from AccountManager.

Comment: I think the OP is asking if he can use the AuthToken as a primary key - in which case the answer is No.

Comment: What could use instead? The email adress?